# SQL Developer connections not opening and TNS file not being read correctly

Tags: database-connection, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am facing 2 issues with my SQL Developer (Version 19.1.0.094) since the last 3 days. Everything was fine before that. And system variables in my local look OK to me.

Issues

1. When I click to connect to a database using an existing/saved connection on the left Connections pane, I get an error pop-up message : Invalid connection information specified. Verify the URL format for the specified driver. Vendor code 0. File attached below
2. The other one is, even though the folder for tnsnames.ora is configured correctly, and the application was reading from that file properly 3 days ago, now its not showing up the full list of tns entries. When I tried to add a new connection using "TNS" from the "connection type" drop-down, the list shown is no where near what I have in the tnsnames.ora file.

Any idea what may have caused this ? Re-install will take time unfortunately :(

Comment: What happened 3 days ago?

Comment: Long weekend !!!  Things were working fine 3 days ago :)

Comment: Do not reinstall. Make sure you have your tns directory specified in the preferences

Comment: @thatjeffsmith yes I do have the tns directory specified. What solution are you proposing if not the re-install (which as I said, in workplaces, take their own time and cadence) ?

Comment: There's no installer, you just unzip the files. Connect where you can, run 'show tns' with F5. I'm guessing we're finding more than one tns file.

Comment: @thatjeffsmith I modified the tns path  in Tools=>Preferences=>TNSnames Directory and gave a path where there is no tnsnames.ora and then restarted. Yet when I go to add a new connection using connection type=TNS, the network alias drop-down shows a lot of entries. Where are they coming from ?

Comment: Show tns, F5...run that like I suggested

Comment: @thatjeffsmith I am not able to connect to any database. As soon as I double-click, I get that error

Comment: Make a basic connection, skip tns